Mi Api rest con Spring Boot no funciona en tomcat 8.5
Tengo un api rest hecho con spring boot y me funciona correctamente en local asi: http://localhost:8080/saludo. Cuando verifico que me funciona correctamente (tambien probe en postaman) procedo a generar el .war. Para ello realice los sigueintes pasos:

<packaging>war</packaging> y el starter de tomcat en mi pom.xml ->

 <!-- ... -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
 <!-- ... -->

 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
     <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>


En la clase que contiene el Main DemoApplication.java agregue la herencia de SpringBootServletInitializer y sobreescribi el metodo configure ->




@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
       return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}




en la la carpeta raiz del proyecto ejecuto el comando mvn clean install para generar el .war
El .war se genera correctamente demo-1.war
En mi tomcat por intefaz grafica subo el .war e intento hacer el get http://localhost:9000/demo-1/saludo pero me da error 404 (ejecutar)



<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Estado HTTP 404 – No encontrado</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        b {
            color: white;
            background-color: #525D76;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 22px;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        a {
            color: black;
        }

        .line {
            height: 1px;
            background-color: #525D76;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Estado HTTP 404 – No encontrado</h1>
    <hr class="line" />
    <p><b>Tipo</b> Informe de estado</p>
    <p><b>mensaje</b> El recurso requerido [&#47;demo-1&#47;saludo&#47;] no se encuentra disponible</p>
    <p><b>Descripción</b> El recurso requerido no está disponible.</p>
    <hr class="line" />
    <h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.100</h3>
</body>

</html>



6. Revisando los logs de tomcat no hay nada util, no se genera ningun error y el .war se carga correctamente.
Leyendo diferentes foros encontre que puede ser la compatibilidad de versiones de java entre el proyecto de spring boot y tomcat. Sin embargo, no estoy seguro.
La version de java que tengo en mi proyecto es java version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16 LTS
Y la del servidor donde esta el tomacat es java version "1.8.0_202"
(Ejecutando java -version en cada maquina).
la veresion de tomcat 8.5
Llevo bastante intentando solucionar este problema y no encuentro solucion alguna. Si necesitan mas informacion en cuanto a codigo u otras cosas no duden en pedirlo.
De antemano gracias.

Resuelto!!
Despues de mucha investigacion logre arreglarlo.
El error es por imcompatibilidad de version de java. (Eso intuyo, no estoy del todo seguro)
Mi tomcat 8.5 tenia la version de jdk 1.8.2_202 (Java 8).
En mi proyecto de spring boot estaba compilando con jdk 17 pues desde la version 3.x en adelante de spring boot solo es compatible desde la 17 en adelante. Por lo que me estaba generando un conflicto de versiones.
Tras investigar un poco las versiones de spring boot que son compatibles con Java 8 son las 2.x por lo que debia crear mi proyecto de spring boot con alguna de esas versiones.
Encontre dos paginas de spring boot initializr que te permiten escoger la version de Java 8.

aliyun
springbootInitializrJava8

¡¡Importante!!
La version de spring boot debe ser menor a las 3.x
Una vez generas el proyecto, puedes crear tu API!
Por ultimo, si quieres usar swagger openapi debes tener en cuenta la version, pues las ultimas versiones no funcionan en este caso.
La version que debes usar es la 1.8.0, es esta la que es compatible con las versiones de springboot 2.x hacia abajo.
Debes añadir a tus dependecia, pom.xml, lo siguiente:
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
</dependency>

Si estas leyendo esto, espero sea de ayuda para ti!
